# Express Js - Is there a way to see the frames/ packets that are being sent from an EJS or HTML form to Express backend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, express, ejs

I have a CS assignment and I'd like to visually show the transfer of data between a frontend and backend (not the full data, but the chunks or how it finds it's way with protocols etc).

Can someone pointy me in the right direction?
Thanks
-1imo

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a packet sniffer such as Wireshark to see the packets being sent from an EJS or HTML form to an Express backend. Wireshark is a free and open source packet analyzer that can be used to monitor and analyze network traffic. With Wireshark, you can see the source and destination of each packet, the type of data being transmitted, and the size of each packet.